# Error: Unsupported type 'viewItem' in Android build

Tags: android, xml

This is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
E:\Saves\Android\Price\app\src\main\res\values\drawables.xml: Error: 
Unsupported type 'viewItem'
```

When clicked on the above error shows these codes that made by android. The file name is drawables.xml

```css
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <viewItem name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</viewItem>
    <viewItem name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</viewItem>
    <viewItem name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</viewItem>
    <viewItem name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</viewItem>
    <viewItem name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</viewItem>
    <viewItem name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</viewItem>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was renaming.
I have renamed the class "ViewItem" to View_Item by studio renaming function.
I renamed all codes and script that included "item" word. :|

Then renamed all "viewItem" to "item" in drawables.xml file and every where that error has raised because of it.